# Wacom Intuos Pro M Scroll Wheel

Tags: gnome, mouse, tablet, wacom

I own a **Wacom Intuos Pro M** and I'm wondering how to use the ring wheel of the pad as a mouse scroll wheel on **Ubuntu 21.10 (gnome)**.

In Ubuntu wacom settings I would like to map the ring wheel to the mouse scroll wheel event (not a keystroke) but I can only assign keystrokes.

In macOS and Win I use the ring wheel a lot, to scroll through the browser pages, zoom in/out in software like Photoshop etc. it seems it's its normal behavior.

Does someone use a Wacom Tablet and use the ring wheel to scroll? How do I do it?

Here the issue on gnome [gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/118).

Thank you.

Comment: Some posts in Gitlab imply that it might work in KDE. Check if it works in  Kubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Gitlab bug you've referenced accurately reflects the current state of things. I'm unsure if GNOME allows you to map the wheel to the arrow keys, but that would be the closest you can get. Even using xsetwacom does not help due to the way that GNOME is implemented. (If you check, xsetwacom will likely report that its already sending the scrollwheel events [buttons 4/5], but GNOME intercepts them for remapping via its own settings before any application can see).